# How to stop my phone from annoying me with software updates?

Tags: updates, notifications, ota-update, system, developer-options

I'm getting constant notifications that a new software-update is available for my phone.

It's a motorola on android 7 and i do **not** want the software-update. I was getting notifications all day getting to the point where it's so aggressive I'd rename my phone to an "updates pager".

I did the following:

```
1) Tap build number 7 times to enable developer mode
2) Settings -> Developer Options -> Disable Automatic System Updates
```

And ever since the *notifications* per se stopped, but the phone still constantly (without the notification tho!) shows an activity (entire screen) telling me that there's a new software update.

[image]

Can someone help me to end my misery? **The phone is not rooted. All stock.**

Comment: Updating keeps your device safe. The update will install secuirty patches. Why don't you want to update?

Comment: I don't like new things. My most used device is actually still on Android 4, I prefer its looks and feel a lot over 5 and newer. Also the newer the version the less of a chance for an exploit to be found that let's me root the device - usually at least.

Comment: If you can run adb on it or via what you are trying in your other questions (via tablet), and if you can pin-point which app is showing that screen/activity about software update, you can try uninstalling that app (for your 'user 0'). **Be warned** that this may result in a boot loop or phone stuck at boot animation. I don't know how critical that app would be. Alternatively, you can skip adb and see if disable option is available under Settings -> Apps -> your system app.